# What will make Monero scale up and get Mass adoption?

Tags: scalability

Right now as we all know Monero just got added to dnm which was precursor to Bitcoin price being pushed up, Monero has been tested for about 3 years and be proven flawless in privacy/anonymity and did not have premine/ico etc... I am curious how Monero will go forward if it needs more people to use it, what initiatives are we taking and what projects are we doing that will say we reach an user base of 1 million users (example Bitcoin has 2 to 3 million users), how are we going to do it?

Answer (score 4):

For mass adoption, we certainly need a simple way (official GUI) to use Monero, since the average user will not be able to run the CLI. It would be also great to see some mobile wallets (with private key control) to adopt Monero. But I am sure, we will see this in the near future.

Most Bitcoin users think that they are anonymous, but law enforcement and some startups are already analysing the blockchain and try to deanonymise step by step. When more people become aware, that they are not anonymous with Bitcoin, they will probably look for alternatives. The first step are tumblers, but you have to trust them and I am not aware of a single tumbler, that is run by a trusted entity. So if they get to know a better alternative, they probably will find Monero.

The whole Monero community can help by spreading the word about the most private and anonymous cryptocurrency available.

However, it is still a long way to mass adoption. First, there will be some speculants joining and causing price fluctuation. The average user wants stability, not speculation and fear of loosing money.

Answer (score 3):

First off, Monero is a technology, not a product.  Technologies do not need any marketing on itself if they are useful enough.

It is needed though to show the first adapters of the technology that Monero is indeed useful enough. For that there are some initiatives going already, like the recent video that was made or the websites and reddit pages.

Mass adoption will only occur though if people see a reason to use private, fungible money. It is very well possible in the future that some bitcoins will get 'tainted' and therefore, loose their fungibility (interchangeability). If that happens, it is possible that people switch to the better solution, which is Monero.

Answer (score 2):

As you've pointed out, most of the world population isn't even using Bitcoin yet. However, as governments continue to limit cash transactions in favor of moving to all digital transactions, a digital privacy niche is being created. People that seek financial privacy in their own digital transactions will naturally gravitate towards the most secure/ private option, which at this time is Monero. For this to happen quickly, it will take much discussion amongst Monero users and each of our individual social networks.